# Koin share dependencies scoped to nested graph

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, koin, navigation-architecture, koin-scope

I'm wondering how to properly scope dependencies with Koin library.

Since Google recommends a [single `Activity` architecture](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/use-android-jetpack-to-accelerate-your.html?m=1) the [AndroidX Navigation lib](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) has become a key library to facilitate this by easily swapping `Fragment`s.

A typical modern Android app has multiple features separated in packages and/or `Gradle` modules.
These feature modules provides a graph that can be used in the root graph as nested graphs. (See picture)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_graph_feature_a" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_graph_feature_b" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.example.androidx_navigation.MainFragment"
        android:label="MainFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_featureAFragment1"
            app:destination="@id/nav_graph_feature_a" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_featureBFragment1"
            app:destination="@id/nav_graph_feature_b" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

[image: Koin scoping of feature modules]

Following rules should be respected:

- Every layer represent a scope.
- Inner layers can inject anything defined in outer layers.
- Layers that do not have an overlap should not be able to inject each other's dependencies.
- Leaving a layer should dispose of its dependencies.

More concretely:

- FeatureA can inject Activity and App dependencies, but not FeatureB dependencies
- FeatureB can inject Activity and App dependencies, but not FeatureA dependencies

How to achieve this in Koin?

> Note that sharing dependencies is not limited to ViewModel only.
> I should be able to share any arbitrary class within my scope.

Comment: I also created a starter demo project that you can use to get started on a solution.
https://github.com/timrijckaert/koin/tree/unclear-unload-per-feature/koin-projects/examples/androidx-navigation

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I think you can use `loadModule` and `unLoadModule` in your feature Modules and with some layer modules like `network` `uiKit` and ... control their needs.

`FeatureA can inject Activity and App dependencies, but not FeatureB dependencies`

I think this is not reasonable that inject your appModule in the FeatueA, you can have a `coreModule` and add this in your all modules that needed, also you can find your activity with `requireActivity()` in your fragmnet for example:D, so the FeatureA never can inject FeatureB dependencies, because they have no access to each other.

Comment: I played already with load- unloadModule, but was unable to make it work with permission change/process death. Mind that once a module is initialised it can not be re added with loadModule.
Also consider navigating to FeatureA and then back to FeatureB I will be able to inject FeatureA dependencies if I can not unload the FeatureAModule first.

Please give it a try with the provided sample if you want

Comment: You can try and fork https://github.com/timrijckaert/koin/tree/unclear-unload-per-feature/koin-projects/examples/androidx-navigation
To see if your idea works

Comment: Why you should inject FeatureA dependencies when it's not present(navigating to FeatureA and then back to FeatureB )? I will definitely take a look at the project at the first opportunity.

Comment: You misunderstand what I mean.

Comment: When you navigate to FeatureA en only call loadModules navigating to FeatureB will still have access to FeatureA dependencies if you don't call unloadModules somewhere.